# PDO Prepared Statements with % and concat

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am converting some MySQL queries in PHP into PDO prepared statement queries.

Most queries are simple enough, but I have come across a couple of queries and I Am not sure how they should look

in the regular queries I am converting:

```
where field ='$type'
```

into

```
where field =:type
```

and changing

```
$results->execute();
```

into

$results->execute(array('type'=>$type));

**Scenario 1**

usually when converting them the variable becomes :type in the query, but with the % there does it become :type% or :type'%'

```
where field like '$type%'
```

**Scenario 2**

When concat in used

```
concat(uuid(),'-$id')
```

how is this supposed to be handled? how do I handle this when there is a - in front of the variable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you need to understand is that [a placeholder have to represent a **complete data literal** only](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#like).

And thus your code will be:

**Scenario 1**

Create a search string with wildcard characters in PHP,

```
$type = "$type%";
```

and then you can bind it the usual way.

**Scenario 2**

Just add one more argument for CONCAT():

```
concat(uuid(),'-', :id)
```

Comment: Can also use binding and `CONCAT` for scenario #1... `WHERE field LIKE CONCAT(:type, '%')`

Answer (score -2):

In scenarion 1 you should do the same as the simple ones

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");
$smt = $pdo->prepare("...... WHERE col=:type");
```

Scenarion 1:

```
$smt->bindParam(":type", $type . '%' , PDO::PARAM_STRING);
```

Scenarion 2:

```
$smt->bindParam(":type", concat(uuid(),"-$id") , PDO::PARAM_STRING);
```

After that you just execute and do your own stuff:

```
$smt->execute();
```

Comment: can you explain why please ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix In your scenario 1, `bindParam` expects a variable (not a value). In your scenario 2, PHP doesn't have any built-in functions called `concat()` or `uuid()`.